# Proving collinearity of the roots without finding the roots.

Tags: polynomials, roots

I was solving the polynomial $2z^3-(3-3i)z^2-(1+i)=0$ and found that they were in fact collinear!

My question is, is there a way to prove that they are collinear without explicitly finding the roots?

My thoughts so far:

- If the roots are collinear, then surely they are just multiples of each other?
- If the above is true, then we need only prove that the roots are somehow in the form $\alpha, k_1 \alpha, k_2 \alpha$ for some $k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{R}$
- If I can show that the sum of roots (some multiple of alpha) and the sum of the roots in pairs (some multiple of alpha squared) is a multiple of the product of roots (some multiple of alpha cubed), then this is sufficient to prove the required result?

Edit to the last point above, I can see that the sum of roots in pairs is zero, so this won't work. Why is that?

Comment: Roots would only be multiples of each other if the line they form passes through $0+0i$

Comment: So am I correct in saying the following then: The method above doesn't work because although the roots are collinear, they do not necessarily have to be multiples of each other since the line passing through the roots may not pass through the origin?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.